# Updating to Ubuntu 19.04 from 18.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 18.10, 19.04

I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.10 distribution to 19.04 but everytime I run the update command (`sudo apt update`) I get the following errors:

> E: Fallo al obtener http://repos.uclv.edu.cu/ubuntu/dists/disco/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 404  Not Found [IP: 10.12.1.62 80]
>
> E: Fallo al obtener http://repos.uclv.edu.cu/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 404  Not Found [IP: 10.12.1.62 80]
>
> E: Fallo al obtener http://repos.uclv.edu.cu/ubuntu/dists/disco-security/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 404  Not Found [IP: 10.12.1.62 80]
>
> E: Fallo al obtener http://repos.uclv.edu.cu/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 404  Not Found [IP: 10.12.1.62 80]
>
> E: Fallo al obtener http://repos.uclv.edu.cu/ubuntu/dists/disco-proposed/main/cnf/Commands-amd64 404  Not Found [IP: 10.12.1.62 80]

Can anyone please assist me with getting this resolved?

Comment: Are you on some kind of wifi or similar network with a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)?

Comment: @vidarlo There is no captive portal on the network.

Comment: The mirrors seem wrong, the links don't work for me too. Try another mirror. If you don't know what I'm talking about, please post the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @pLumo I am on a network that is behind a proxy server which does not allow me to use external sources.

Comment: You should ask your internet provider how to proceed. Usually a proxy should not block the internet o0... If that is not possible and you are not able to access the internet, you can refer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 1):

Try using different Sources List. Here's funky generator that'll help you out:

```
https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/
```

Comment: I am not able to use external sources as the network is behind a proxy.